# Displaying images via link from database ? (PHP/MYSQLI) NEWBIE

Tags: php, mysql, display

Is it okay if i store links in the database to the  images and then just display them in the website ? is this a bad practice ? Example code below

```
<?
  echo "<img src='/projects".$row['image']."' >";
```

Comment: Yes. Does that work ?

Comment: no, it is fine, but a much better approach is to keep your images in on place and just store names or ids in the DB: `"<img src='/projects/product-".$row['image-id'].".png' >"`

Comment: It's fine - so long as you ensure your saved image names are sanitized/normalized.

Comment: In some ways this is actually a good practice. However, I strongly recommend you use absolute URLs and store the entire URL in the DB

Comment: @Nicholas Summers  storing absolute paths locks you out of using multiple environments and syncing Databases from prod to dev for example

Comment: Much better to store the images and as @Auris states IMHO. But I suppose it depends on what you're trying to achieve as there's probably a reason you've decided to use a database to store them.

Comment: Perhaps some of these comments could be posted as an expanded answer? I for one would be interested in the approach of more seasoned programmers @Auris?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as requested by the comments.
  Depending on your application and it's complexity, you would want to simplify your image loading as much as possible and storing image url's in the DB isn't the best approach. ideally you would want to group your images in to directories by type and keep a common structure to image names so that you could easily swap images with only replacing thair id or single string. Here is an example of a very simplified image loader class:

Directory structure:

```
images
    -> products
        -> product-123.png
    -> icons
        -> arrow.png
```

Image loader class:

```
class ImageLoader {
    const IMAGE_PATH = '/images'
    const PROCUCT_IMAGE_PATH = '/products/'
    const ICON_IMAGE_PATH = '/icons'
    const IMAGE_EXTENSION = '.png'

    static public function getIconImage($identifier) {
        return self::IMAGE_PATH 
            . self::ICON_IMAGE_PATH 
            . $identifier 
            . self::IMAGE_EXTENSION;
    }

    static public function getProductImage($identifier) {
        return self::IMAGE_PATH 
            . self::PROCUCT_IMAGE_PATH 
            . 'product-'
            . $identifier 
            . self::IMAGE_EXTENSION;
    }
}
```

Usage

Manually passing image name:

```
<img src="<?= ImageLoader::getIconImage('arrow') ?>" />
```

Passing a variable as id stored in the DB:

```
<img src="<?= ImageLoader::getProductImage($productIdFromDatabase) ?>" />
```

Comment: wow thats an amazing code, tnx for the advice this should make things a lot easier